Erasing an element from a vector in C++
I'm trying to remove the negative elements from a vector (lesser than 0) using the below code, however whenever a vector has a negative as its last element I'm getting an error(Segmentation fault)
int main()
{
    //Initializing the vector
    vector<int> A={5,4,3,1,1,-1};
     // iterator
    vector<int> :: iterator iter;
    
    //Printing the vector
    for(iter=A.begin();iter!=A.end();iter++)
    {
         cout<<(*iter)<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    
    //Deleting the integers lesser than 1
    for(iter=A.begin();iter!=A.end();iter++)
    {
        if((*iter)<1)
        {
            A.erase(iter);
        }
    }
   
    
    return 0;
}


I'm trying to remove the negative elements from a vector (lesser than 0) -- There is no need for all of the (buggy) code.  This is just A.erase(std::remove_if(A.begin(), A.end(), [](int n) { return n < 0; }), A.end());

See this.

Nitpick but x < 0 would be a test if x is negative, not x < 1

The iterator is no longer valid for the ++ in the for loop after you erase the item it points to from the vector.
The erase function returns the next iterator. You can see the correct loop style in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end();)
{
    if (*it % 2 == 0)
        it = c.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}


For some reason you changed the test, the original code had (*iter) < 1.
